# lxml parse py-postgresql xml output

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, lxml

I have sql-query returning xml-typed rows in PostgreSQL. And I want to append those rows to lxml element in python.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
#doing db connection here, declare a query text etc.

root = ET.Element('root')
res = db.query(querytext)
for row in res:
  root.append(row[0]) #<- and here i'm getting error
```

Error is "expected lxml.etree._element got xml.etree.ElementTree.element"

So how can I convert xml.etree.ElementTree.element to lxml.etree._element? Or I need to do this in some other way? Another xml lib maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the xml from string:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
#doing db connection here, declare a query text etc.

root = ET.Element('root')
#res = db.query(querytext)

res = [
    ('<foo>1</foo>', ),
    ('<foo>2</foo>', )
]

for row in res:
  root.append(ET.fromstring(row[0]))

print(ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

returns:

```
b'<root>\n  <foo>1</foo>\n  <foo>2</foo>\n</root>\n'
```

Comment: But the problem is that I'm getting <Element 'Item' at 0x000000D38BF8D0E8> from postgresql. It's not a string.